# mongoose find x docs for specific filed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of videos, each video doc has user_id.
I need to get the last 5 videos of each user.

don't know where to start... tried grouping without any success.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this pipeline a try:

```java
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { _id: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            videos: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            user_id: "$_id",
            videos: { $slice: ["$videos", 5] }
        }
    }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NOOJDnfIhk

**explanation:**

1. with the first stage, you $sort the whole collection in descending order on the _id field. sorting initially is necessary because there's no operator in mongo that can sort the grouped items afaik.
2. then you group by user_id field. we $push all documents of each group to a new field called videos. $$ROOT variable gives you access to all docs of each group.
3. the final $project stage uses $slice to pick only the top 5 items in the videos array from the previous stage and sets it on a field of the same name.

Comment: it worked! now I just need to understand what happened here :)

Comment: and how can I populate the user..?